# Making a container view able after selecting desired checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want a container to become visible once 3 check boxes are selected so I created this code to make it visible on condition but
it's giving **identifier expected error** even though syntax seems to be correct.

Is there anything wrong in this code?

```
//to set limit for number of checkboxes to be selected and to make rest container visible

//to set limit for number of checkboxes to be selected
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#table").on("click", function () {
        var limit = 4,
        do {
            checkboxes.not(":checked").attr("disabled", valid);
            $('.container').show();
            $('input').iCheck('update');
        } while (checkboxes = $(this).find("input:checkbox"),
            valid = checkboxes.filter(":checked").length >= limit;);
});
});
```

Comment: There are no syntax errors in the code you posted as far as I can see, can you post a [MCVE]? What line does the error occur on?

Comment: Please click the `<>` button and add relevant HTML and libraries. For example what is iCheck?

Comment: sorry people i posted the same code without do while implemented! this is the code that causing problem again really sorry if i caused some of your valuable time :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using do while for this to display the container once 3 check boxes are selected. any specific reason? the code in the do will always execute atleast once regardless of condition is while.

You could acheive the same using below code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#table").on("click", function() {
        var limit = 3,
            checkboxes = $(this).find("input:checkbox"),
            valid = checkboxes.filter(":checked").length >= limit;
        if(valid) {
            checkboxes.not(":checked").attr("disabled", valid);
            $('.container').show();
        }
        $('input').iCheck('update');
    });
});
```